# How can 'String#reverse' return non-'String' objects?

Tags: ruby, equality, return-type

I have a class `Word`:

```
class Word < String
end

w = Word.new("level")
y = w.reverse
y.class # => Word
```

1) How is this possible? `Word#reverse` should return a `String` because it inherits `String#reverse`, which returns a `String`.

I added this code:

```
class Word < String
  attr_accessor :s

  def magic
    @s = Time.now
  end
end

y.magic
sleep(5)
w.magic
y.s == w # => false
y == w # => true
```

2) `w` and `y` are `Word`, and are equal, hence they both have the same methods, such as `magic`. Where did `y` acquire the `magic` method?

3) How come `y == w` evaluates to `true` while `y.s` and `w.s` return unequal values?

Comment: I am not sure what your second question means.

Answer (score 7):

While the documentation for [`String#reverse`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-reverse) states:

> Returns a new string with the characters from str in reverse order.

and so you might expect a return type of `String`, if you pop open the method you can see the line

```
rev = rb_str_new_with_class(str, 0, RSTRING_LEN(str));
```

and that `rev` is what actually gets returned. My C is fairly rusty, but looking around the C code for ruby, that method `rb_str_new_with_class` seems to be doing exactly what it says, it creates a new instance of whatever class `str` is, in this case `Word`. So, what the documentation means when it says it returns a new string, is that it returns a new instance of whatever class this string is, which in most cases is `String`.

So knowing that it creates a new instance of whatever class the current string is, it's easy to see how `w.reverse` ended up having a `magic` method...because `Word` gave it the method, and it is a `Word`.

And finally, how are they equal? You don't define a new `==` method on `Word`, so it takes the parent [`String#==`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-3D-3D) method, which doesn't know or care that there are instance variables and just compares the values of the string, coercing things using `to_str` if necessary and able, you could even do:

```
Word.new("level") == "level" # => true
```

(Note: I'm not actually sure if `Word` gets coerced or not.)